# How to implement a Key Toggle for GUI instead of mouse click in Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a Frame GUI, I want to make it where when a player has the GUI when they're running the game, that they can press a certain key to toggle it (ON) and (OFF). So an Open/Close System. Instead of using a Mouse Click I want a key toggle. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Keyboard_input
This link explains 2 ways, the better way is the top or here:

```
local toggle = false -- false is Off; true is On


function onKeyPress(actionName, userInputState, inputObject)
    if userInputState == Enum.UserInputState.Begin then
        print("R was pressed")
        if toggle == false then
             toggle = true
              -- INSERT Making GUI Visible
        else
            toggle = false
            -- INSERT making GUI Invisible
        end
    end
end

game.ContextActionService:BindAction("keyPress", onKeyPress, false, Enum.KeyCode.R)
```

-- The above line could also been written as:
    -- game.ContextActionService:BindAction("keyPress", onKeyPress, false, "r")

Comment: To invert the toggle state, use `toggle = not toggle` instead